# Bash - Why doesn't sfdisk work in this script?

Tags: linux, bash

**UPDATE**: As per suggestions, I have asked this question of the Superuser community. I told them you say hi ;)

https://superuser.com/questions/1193808/why-doesnt-this-sfdisk-script-work

This has been a painful process. Perhaps there's something simple I'm missing..?

I'm trying to create a script to automatically partition a disk with a gpt table and 1 partition that takes up all the space. Should be super simple and straight forward..

I found the `sfdisk` command which is the (supposedly) script-friendly version of fdisk.

The best I've got so far is:

```
sfdisk --color=always --wipe always --no-reread --no-act --label gpt /dev/sdc
```

There's the matter of the partition type, which is to be `Linux Filesystem` (is that a good choice for a data drive?). The GUID for that is `0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4`

When I run the above command, I get an interactive prompt. This is a bit of a problem for my script ;)

What of the input/output format described in the man pages?

`<name>: <value>, <name>: <value>, ...`

It seems to be suggesting I do something like:

`echo 'label: gpt' | --color=always --wipe always --no-reread --no-act /dev/sdc`

but, alas, that fails harder than the above. :(

```
Partitioning /dev/sdc...

Disk /dev/sdc: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

>>> line 1: unsupported command

New situation: Leaving.
```

Then there's the dumpfile I caught wind of in the depths of the man pages. It seems to suggest that I can create these cursed things, cat them, and pipe to sfdisk. (Un?)fortunately, I can't hardcode most of this so the solution won't work for me:

```
label: gpt
label-id: 236AEC41-D407-4FE5-94FA-8550C2CA10B5
device: /dev/sdc
unit: sectors
first-lba: 2048
last-lba: 5860533134

/dev/sdc1 : start=        2048, size=  5860531087, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4,uuid=8D7D48B0-8BF5-4383-B0EC-615C0E8AF4B4
```

What am I doing wrong!?
Thanks :)

Comment: `-f` should do the trick

Comment: I'm hesitant to force an action when I don't understand why it doesn't work. What's with the interactive prompt? What of that output format (`<name>: <value>, <name>: <value>, ...`) suggesting I do something like `echo 'label: gpt' | sfdisk ...`?

Comment: Just tried your command, ok `-f` (alone) makes no sense here. Yes, the problem is that you are not specifying a partition table. You need to pipe that to the command. A simple start would be to (1) create partitions manually using the interactive command on a test system (2) dump that partition table through `sfdisk -d /dev/testdev > part.table.txt`. Looking at `part.table.txt` you'll get an idea how the commands look like. Optional (3): use `sfdisk -f /dev/foo < part.table.txt` to dump that to other disks.

Comment: Ok. I did that. I put the contents of the generated file in my question.

Comment: What about `--label gpt`? That would seem to do the same thing as piping in `label: gpt`..

Comment: I'm getting mixed up over specifiying types at the table level and partition level... hmm

Comment: I told you anything I know. At the end of the day you'll know more than me ;)

Comment: But still not enough to format this cursed drive! Hah

Comment: Thanks for your help, brave soul! I wish you all the best in your journey :)

Comment: :) I recommend to ask the question on superuser.com. You might get better responses there.

Comment: Your question is probably more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). You will get many more useful answers (and fewer downvotes) if you post this question to an appropriate site. That said, why are you using `sfdisk` instead of `fdisk` if you are having trouble with the script aspect of it?. If you need to partition multiple disks with the same scheme, do the first in `fdisk`, then use `sfdisk` to dump the scheme apply it to other disks (handy for RAID, etc.)

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: As this is a scripting (ie code as opposed to administration) question I figured I would ask on here. It was a tough decision, tbh.

Comment: Hopefully I don't get downvoted! :'(  .... It's a perfectly cromulent question..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm using sfdisk instead of fdisk because it's billed as the scriptable version of fdisk (non-interactive, less output, etc). This question is a simplification from a script I'm writing. I didn't want to bore you all with unnecessary details haha

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Confusingly, it is possible to interactively use `sfdisk` to create and then dump a partition table config to a file. I posted the results of that to my question.

Comment: No, no, I get what you are doing, I've done it many times. I have 3 servers spinning 14 disks in 10 RAID sets. I use fdisks/sfdisk all the time. My point was this, If you are having trouble with the non-interactive script aspects of sfdisk, simply use the interactive fdisk, and then dump the results. The interactive commands you use can be translated into the scriptable commands needed with sfdisk without guessing which ones you need. Or, you can simply read your config created in fdisk in sfdisk and dump a file that you can use to duplicate the partition scheme. Both are fine.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I see you do. I'm writing some scripts for my first little cloud. In time, not so little, I hope :)

Comment: Unfortunately, no love yet on superuser.. probably too programm-y a question for them (and too admin-y for here ... sigh)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I've been thinking of doing that, I don't want to have to maintain a(nother lol) collection of templates.. plus, there are IDs in the output that I wouldn't be able to know beforehand, plus other hardware-specific details such as sector counts, etc.. Nah, the front door is the answer! haha

Comment: (This is coming from a larger bunch of scripts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better way: `sgdisk`

```
sgdisk --clear $blkdev
sgdisk --new=0:0:0 --typecode=0:0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4 $blkdev
```

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the interactive prompt:

Try adding `<<< exit` to the end of the *sfdisk* command line:

```
sfdisk --color=always --wipe always --no-reread --no-act --label gpt /dev/sdc <<< exit
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).